# trace-cmd by process ID seems not working

Tags: ftrace

I am working on a SUSE linux work node and want to find out some performance issue on it.

The linux kernel looks as below:

```
5.3.18-24.99-default #1 SMP Sun Jan 23 19:03:51 UTC 2022 (712a8e6) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After installing trace-cmd, I am able to get trace result using the command like `trace-cmd record -p function_graph ls`.

But when it comes to process id like `trace-cmd record -p function_graph -P 87166`, I find nothing is toggled, actually the process exist in the system.

```
 **87166** root      20   0 21.829g 577592  22040 S 33.33 0.748 456:41.80 java

root      87166  86790 29 Oct06 ?        07:39:39 java -server -Dservice.log.base.dir=/var/log/java-performance-benchmark -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/jvm/java-performance-benchmark_hs_err.log -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -jar /opt/java-performance-benchmark/java-performance-benchmark-app.jar

worker-pool1-p1aooifw-eccd-ibd-udm80635:/home/eccd # trace-cmd record -P 87166 -p function_graph
  plugin 'function_graph'
Hit Ctrl^C to stop recording
^CCPU0 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU1 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU2 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU3 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU4 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU5 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU6 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU7 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU8 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU9 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU10 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU11 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU12 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU13 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU14 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU15 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU16 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
CPU17 data recorded at offset=0x646000
    0 bytes in size
```

How could I debug such an issue?